# Transparent backgrounds in IE over an image slideshow

Tags: html

I am working on page that has a text box over an image slideshow.  The text box has a transparent background-image defined.  In all browsers, the transparency works as expected when the page first loads up.  However, in IE7 (and presumably other versions, but haven't gotten their yet) the transparency doesn't work when image changes.

Searching around hasn't indicated where the problem lies, so I'm having a hard time determining the fix.  I've tried changing the z-indexes (maybe background image was below the slideshow image) without any luck.

Any come across a similar problem?

---

I should also note that I am using a png for alpha transparency.  When the slideshow image changes, the div text box shows up, but does not appear to have the image background.

Comment: can you post some code or a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS

img
    {
    opacity:0.4;
    filter:alpha(opacity=40);
    }
this link will help you http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp